# Minimize $\sum_{i=1}^M x_i e^{y_i}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

everyone. I want to minimize an objective function
\begin{equation}
  \min_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}} \ \sum_{i=1}^M x_i e^{y_i},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^M$. As far as I know, the objective function is non-convex, because if $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are scalar, we can derive the Hessian as
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & e^y\\ e^y & xe^y \end{bmatrix}, 
\end{equation}
which is negative definite, so the original objective function is concave.

So who can tell me how to minimize my objective function? Here I don't list the constraints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The objective function is the inner product of two vectors: $<x_i>$ and $<e^{y_i}>$  and $i=1,\cdots ,M$. if you set $y_i=0$ and $x_i \rightarrow -\infty $ then the minimum of the function is clearly unbounded.

Comment: Actually, $x_i, \forall i$ are Boolean, and I have a constraint on $y_i$ as $\sum_{i=1}^My_i \leq y_{\max}$. So my idea to optimize the objective function is that, first fix $y$ as initialization and use convex programming to solve $x$; then based on the obtained $x$ solve $y$. Does this idea make sense? Can it obtain global optimum? Or does anyone know some optimization techniques for solving this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

You want your function to be stationary at the minimum that is
$$df(x, y)=\nabla_{\bf{x}}f(x, y)\cdot{d\bf{x}}+\nabla_{\bf{y}}f(x, y)\cdot{d\bf{y}}=0$$

Comment: Actually, $x_i, \forall i$ are Boolean, and I have a constraint on $y_i$ as $\sum_{i=1}^My_i \leq y_{\max}$. So my idea to optimize the objective function is that, first fix $y$ as initialization and use convex programming to solve $x$; then based on the obtained $x$ solve $y$. Does this idea make sense? Can it obtain global optimum? Or does anyone know some optimization techniques for solving this kind of problems?